# Motion-Based Multiple Object Tracking Matlab Example to Record Each Object Centroid at Each Time Point and Calculate Respective Velocity

Tags: matlab, feature-detection, matlab-cvst, centroid

I'm trying to develop an object tracking script that finds all of the object's centroids at each time point so that I can then calculate their velocity based on the time between each frame. I'm using the tutorial Motion-Based Multiple Object Tracking and have been able to successfully get that to work with my video, but now I'm trying to figure out how to extract the centroid data of each object and subsequently calculate the velocity! Please let me know if you have any recommendations!

Best, Ben

```
  function multiObjectTracking()
  % Create System objects used for reading video, detecting moving objects,
  % and displaying the results.
  obj = setupSystemObjects();
  tracks = initializeTracks(); % Create an empty array of tracks.
  nextId = 1; % ID of the next track
  % Detect moving objects, and track them across video frames.
  while ~isDone(obj.reader)
      frame = readFrame();
      [centroids, bboxes, mask] = detectObjects(frame);
      predictNewLocationsOfTracks();
      [assignments, unassignedTracks, unassignedDetections] = ...
          detectionToTrackAssignment();
      updateAssignedTracks();
      updateUnassignedTracks();
      deleteLostTracks();
      createNewTracks();
      displayTrackingResults();
  end
   function obj = setupSystemObjects()
          % Initialize Video I/O
          % Create objects for reading a video from a file, drawing the tracked
          % objects in each frame, and playing the video.
          % Create a video file reader.
          obj.reader = vision.VideoFileReader('Beads.wmv');
          % Create two video players, one to display the video,
          % and one to display the foreground mask.
          obj.videoPlayer = vision.VideoPlayer('Position', [20, 400, 700, 400]);
          obj.maskPlayer = vision.VideoPlayer('Position', [740, 400, 700, 400]);
          % Create System objects for foreground detection and blob analysis
          % The foreground detector is used to segment moving objects from
          % the background. It outputs a binary mask, where the pixel value
          % of 1 corresponds to the foreground and the value of 0 corresponds
          % to the background.
          obj.detector = vision.ForegroundDetector('NumGaussians', 3, ...
              'NumTrainingFrames', 40, 'MinimumBackgroundRatio', 0.7);
          % Connected groups of foreground pixels are likely to correspond to moving
          % objects.  The blob analysis System object is used to find such groups
          % (called 'blobs' or 'connected components'), and compute their
          % characteristics, such as area, centroid, and the bounding box.
          obj.blobAnalyser = vision.BlobAnalysis('BoundingBoxOutputPort', true, ...
              'AreaOutputPort', true, 'CentroidOutputPort', true, ...
              'MinimumBlobArea', 400);
   end
   function tracks = initializeTracks()
          % create an empty array of tracks
          tracks = struct(...
              'id', {}, ...
              'bbox', {}, ...
              'kalmanFilter', {}, ...
              'age', {}, ...
              'totalVisibleCount', {}, ...
              'consecutiveInvisibleCount', {});
   end
   function frame = readFrame()
          frame = obj.reader.step();
   end
   function [centroids, bboxes, mask] = detectObjects(frame)
          % Detect foreground.
          mask = obj.detector.step(frame);
          % Apply morphological operations to remove noise and fill in holes.
          mask = imopen(mask, strel('rectangle', [3,3]));
          mask = imclose(mask, strel('rectangle', [15, 15]));
          mask = imfill(mask, 'holes');
          % Perform blob analysis to find connected components.
          [~, centroids, bboxes] = obj.blobAnalyser.step(mask);
   end
   function predictNewLocationsOfTracks()
          for i = 1:length(tracks)
              bbox = tracks(i).bbox;
              % Predict the current location of the track.
              predictedCentroid = predict(tracks(i).kalmanFilter);
              % Shift the bounding box so that its center is at
              % the predicted location.
              predictedCentroid = int32(predictedCentroid) - bbox(3:4) / 2;
              tracks(i).bbox = [predictedCentroid, bbox(3:4)];
          end
   end
   function [assignments, unassignedTracks, unassignedDetections] = ...
              detectionToTrackAssignment()
          nTracks = length(tracks);
          nDetections = size(centroids, 1);
          % Compute the cost of assigning each detection to each track.
          cost = zeros(nTracks, nDetections);
          for i = 1:nTracks
              cost(i, :) = distance(tracks(i).kalmanFilter, centroids);
          end
          % Solve the assignment problem.
          costOfNonAssignment = 20;
          [assignments, unassignedTracks, unassignedDetections] = ...
              assignDetectionsToTracks(cost, costOfNonAssignment);
   end
  function updateAssignedTracks()
          numAssignedTracks = size(assignments, 1);
          for i = 1:numAssignedTracks
              trackIdx = assignments(i, 1);
              detectionIdx = assignments(i, 2);
              centroid = centroids(detectionIdx, :);
              bbox = bboxes(detectionIdx, :);
              % Correct the estimate of the object's location
              % using the new detection.
              correct(tracks(trackIdx).kalmanFilter, centroid);
              % Replace predicted bounding box with detected
              % bounding box.
              tracks(trackIdx).bbox = bbox;
              % Update track's age.
              tracks(trackIdx).age = tracks(trackIdx).age + 1;
              % Update visibility.
              tracks(trackIdx).totalVisibleCount = ...
                  tracks(trackIdx).totalVisibleCount + 1;
              tracks(trackIdx).consecutiveInvisibleCount = 0;
          end
  end
   function updateUnassignedTracks()
          for i = 1:length(unassignedTracks)
              ind = unassignedTracks(i);
              tracks(ind).age = tracks(ind).age + 1;
              tracks(ind).consecutiveInvisibleCount = ...
                  tracks(ind).consecutiveInvisibleCount + 1;
          end
   end
  function deleteLostTracks()
          if isempty(tracks)
              return;
          end
          invisibleForTooLong = 20;
          ageThreshold = 8;
          % Compute the fraction of the track's age for which it was visible.
          ages = [tracks(:).age];
          totalVisibleCounts = [tracks(:).totalVisibleCount];
          visibility = totalVisibleCounts ./ ages;
          % Find the indices of 'lost' tracks.
          lostInds = (ages < ageThreshold & visibility < 0.6) | ...
              [tracks(:).consecutiveInvisibleCount] >= invisibleForTooLong;
          % Delete lost tracks.
          tracks = tracks(~lostInds);
  end
   function createNewTracks()
          centroids = centroids(unassignedDetections, :);
          bboxes = bboxes(unassignedDetections, :);
          for i = 1:size(centroids, 1)
              centroid = centroids(i,:);
              bbox = bboxes(i, :);
              % Create a Kalman filter object.
              kalmanFilter = configureKalmanFilter('ConstantVelocity', ...
                  centroid, [200, 50], [100, 25], 100);
              % Create a new track.
              newTrack = struct(...
                  'id', nextId, ...
                  'bbox', bbox, ...
                  'kalmanFilter', kalmanFilter, ...
                  'age', 1, ...
                  'totalVisibleCount', 1, ...
                  'consecutiveInvisibleCount', 0);
              % Add it to the array of tracks.
              tracks(end + 1) = newTrack;
              % Increment the next id.
              nextId = nextId + 1;
          end
   end
   function displayTrackingResults()
          % Convert the frame and the mask to uint8 RGB.
          frame = im2uint8(frame);
          mask = uint8(repmat(mask, [1, 1, 3])) .* 255;
          minVisibleCount = 8;
          if ~isempty(tracks)
              % Noisy detections tend to result in short-lived tracks.
              % Only display tracks that have been visible for more than
              % a minimum number of frames.
              reliableTrackInds = ...
                  [tracks(:).totalVisibleCount] > minVisibleCount;
              reliableTracks = tracks(reliableTrackInds);
              % Display the objects. If an object has not been detected
              % in this frame, display its predicted bounding box.
              if ~isempty(reliableTracks)
                  % Get bounding boxes.
                  bboxes = cat(1, reliableTracks.bbox);
                  % Get ids.
                  ids = int32([reliableTracks(:).id]);
                  % Create labels for objects indicating the ones for
                  % which we display the predicted rather than the actual
                  % location.
                  labels = cellstr(int2str(ids'));
                  predictedTrackInds = ...
                      [reliableTracks(:).consecutiveInvisibleCount] > 0;
                  isPredicted = cell(size(labels));
                  isPredicted(predictedTrackInds) = {' predicted'};
                  labels = strcat(labels, isPredicted);
                  % Draw the objects on the frame.
                  frame = insertObjectAnnotation(frame, 'rectangle', ...
                      bboxes, labels);
                  % Draw the objects on the mask.
                  mask = insertObjectAnnotation(mask, 'rectangle', ...
                      bboxes, labels);
              end
          end
          % Display the mask and the frame.
          obj.maskPlayer.step(mask);
          obj.videoPlayer.step(frame);
   end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the centroid of the object in every frame, you can compute its velocity in pixels/frame by subtracting consecutive centroids.